# Can i create view in mysql that will sum all the column base on the other column?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that with **account type** and **amount** 
There are only two types of account (Savings and Credit):[image]

I create a view that will group all the sum of amount based on the type of account.

The table may look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a conditional aggregation

```
create view your_view_name as 
select id, 
       sum(case when account = 'savings' then ammount else 0 end) as saving,
       sum(case when account = 'credit' then ammount else 0 end) as credit
from your_table
group by id
```